# How to connect table with Month and year data with calendar table in Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I'm trying to connect a table (Payroll table) who has No. of labour hours by Months of a year. For example:

1. 2017 Jan 10000
2. 2017 Feb 12000

I want to connect this table to my calendar table to perform some calculation on fact table data which i have already connected to my calendar table.

Can anyone please help me creating a relation between Calendar table and Payroll table.

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have a `Date` column in the `Calendar` table, you can use the following DAX expression to create a new column:

```
Year Month = 
YEAR('Calendar'[Date]) & " " & 
FORMAT(DATE(1, MONTH('Calendar'[Date]), 1), "MMM")
```

[image: year month]

Then you can create a one-to-many relationship between the `Year Month` column and the `Month` column from your `Payroll` table:

[image: relationship]